# Git and Git Extensions - no green ticks on files and folders

Tags: version-control, git-extensions

I've moved over to Git for source control. A few months ago I installed Git Extensions (including everything it needs in the install) and everything was fine - create a new repository, then commit some files and the files and folders would then have green ticks.

I installed Git Extensions on my friend's pc (windows 7), did the same steps as above but when going to that directory, none of the folders or files have green or red ticks. Tried going to folder options to change a few settings but still not working.

Any solutions or ideas?

Comment: Maybe you mean TortoiseGit? TortoiseGit provides these symbols.

Comment: good point, TortoiseGit was already installed on the pc I used before GitExtensions. Perhaps it knows to include them when committing through git extensions. What do you think? maybe I should install tortoisegit

Comment: You should. Because TortoiseGit provides this and it's the only Client i know, that provides this.

Comment: just installed TortoiseGit and did a commit, still nothing. Then tried with git extensions and it also didn't produce the green tick

Comment: did you restart your system?

Comment: funny you ask that, did that just before I saw your post. I see the ticks. Thanks for your help - not sure how to mark a comment as an answer so marked it as a useful comment :)